# How to add config file that is in .gitIgnore to azure pipeline build?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a json config file with connectionStrings and other info that I don't want in the gitHub repository. Is there a way to just add it as a constant static file so that all builds have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the file to the "[Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)" then download the file in the build pipeline and use it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The file will be downloaded to a temp folder in the agent:

```
$(Agent.WorkFolder)\_temp\filename
```

During the build you can take the file from there and use him.